# Repeat set of records for each hour in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime

I have table called "Data". This contains three column Time (datetime), Tag (int), Value (float) Sample data given below

| Time | Tag | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-24 00:00:00 | 1001 | 12 |
| 2022-01-24 00:00:00 | 1002 | 50 |
| 2022-01-24 00:00:00 | 1003 | 24 |
| 2022-01-24 01:00:00 | 1001 | 0 |
| 2022-01-24 02:00:00 | 1001 | 34 |
| 2022-01-24 02:00:00 | 1002 | 45 |
| 2022-01-24 02:00:00 | 1003 | 10 |

From the above table you can make out that there is a timestamp that is missing for tags 1002 and 1003 because there are no values for those tags at 2022-01-24 01:00:00

However I want to create a query that can fill my missing timestamps for the tag that does not have value with null value

Out put table should be like this

| Time | Tag | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-24 00:00:00 | 1001 | 12 |
| 2022-01-24 00:00:00 | 1002 | 50 |
| 2022-01-24 00:00:00 | 1003 | 24 |
| 2022-01-24 01:00:00 | 1001 | 0 |
| 2022-01-24 01:00:00 | 1002 | null |
| 2022-01-24 01:00:00 | 1003 | null |
| 2022-01-24 02:00:00 | 1001 | 34 |
| 2022-01-24 02:00:00 | 1002 | 45 |
| 2022-01-24 02:00:00 | 1003 | 10 |

Can anyone help me with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: What is the logic for determining missing rows? How do we know they're not all missing a row for 03:00:00? Look at outer-joining with a calendar table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first generate the full expected data-set using a cross-join of known values, and then outer join this to the existing data. This is assuming your SQL Server tag was correct:

```
with alldates as (
  select [time], tag
  from (select distinct [time] from data)d
  cross join (select distinct tag from data)t
)
select ad.[time], ad.tag, d.[value]
from alldates ad
left join data d on d.[time] = ad.[time] and d.tag = ad.tag
order by ad.[time], ad.tag;
```